# Symfony 4 and webpack encore, looking for good practice when adding a CSS third library

Tags: css, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm on a Symfony 4 new project.

Via yarn, I installed (by example) the CSS library animate.css

`yarn install animate.css`

From the webpack.config.js file, I added the animate.css file like that :

`.addStyleEntry('animate', './node_modules/animate.css/animate.css')`

My question is : is it a good way to add a CSS library like that ? I'm not sure if use directly the node_module path is a good practice..

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you inject it directly in the .js file you are using

ex:

```js
require('animate.css/animate.css')
```

or something in this way depending on your js superset if you have one so it will generate a .css file with your .js

an example is this:
on my first line of my typescript file I call this `import ./style.css`
after that Encore will generate me a nwe .css file that i can use in my template using `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('entry') }}`

Comment: This is the point, and I don't think it is good because I just want load a pure css library,
Is a bit illogical to use a js way for load a pure css no ?

Comment: it is only in compile time, webpack Encore will generate a .css file and you would use this `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('entry') }}` to import your css